# Find hostname from NetBIOS name

Tags: windows, networking, netbios

I have the NetBIOS name of a remote computer, and I want to find its hostname (I'm in a LAN has a DNS server), or the IP address (I'll do a `nslookup` to find the hostname).

A Google search told me to do

```
nbtstat -a NETBIOS-NAME
```

This gives me this output (sorry for the french output)

```
C:\Users\Charles.CHBROSSO-WIN7VM>nbtstat -a LIGHTCT-PC2

Connexion au réseau local 3:
Adresse IP du noeud : [10.10.10.47] ID d'étendue : []

Table de noms NetBIOS des ordinateurs distants

   Nom                Type         État
---------------------------------------------
LIGHTCT-PC2    <00>  UNIQUE      Inscrit
WORKGROUP      <00>  Groupe      Inscrit
LIGHTCT-PC2    <20>  UNIQUE      Inscrit
WORKGROUP      <1E>  Groupe      Inscrit

Adresse MAC = B8-AC-6F-81-8A-26
```

The problem is that `10.10.10.47` is the IP address of the local computer (`CHBROSSO-WIN7VM`).

How can I find the IP address of the remote computer?

Answer (score 2):

If you can communicate/connect with it some how (Ping perhaps?), then `nbtstat -c` should show you the computer and it's resolved IP address.

**EDIT:**

Check out [NBTScan.exe](http://www.inetcat.net/software/nbtscan.html) - a utility that will do a NetBIOS scan of your subnet and return the info including IP and MAC addresses:

> NBTscan is a program for scanning IP networks for NetBIOS name information. It sends NetBIOS status query to each address in supplied range and lists received information in human readable form. For each responded host it lists IP address, NetBIOS computer name, logged-in user name and MAC address.

Hope that helps...

Comment: Thanks; it lists another PC that I believe to be the WINS server

Comment: @CharlesB - Added a link to a utility for you to try out. :)

Comment: Even if it does not exactly answer my question (scanning instead of querying), this tool is very helpful). Thanks!